# apply justify content based on center of divs

Tags: html, css

How can I apply `justify-content: space-between` based on the center of divs? For example let's assume I have three divs of different sizes. I want to make them justify in a way that the second div's center is at the center of its container

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
}

.first {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}

.second {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}

.third {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.center {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 5px);
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="center"></div>
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second"></div>
  <div class="third"></div>
</div>
```

[image]
As you can see, it is not centered. Or in case of four divs, I want the center of container div to be in the middle of second and third divs. Is there a built in way to achieve this behavior? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are the widths of the items dynamic? If not, is the last item supposed to overflow seeing as you have fixed widths?

Comment: I can see what you want the spaces to be if you have three elements. But what if there are four or more? e.g. Taking the case of an even number of elements, how do you want the spaces between the pairs of elements to be distributed? And do you know they will always fit if you make the mid point between the mid two elements centered? In short, what are the constraints to this problem?

Comment: For odd number of elements, I want the element to be centered. For example if I have 5 elements the third one must be centered. And for even number of elements I want the middle of two middle elements to be in center. For example if I have 4 elements, the middle of second and third element must be in center.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I think you will need to use JavaScript for a general solution. Is using JS acceptable? (It isn't in your list of tags).

Comment: It is impossible to come up with a solution until we know how you want the space to be distributed - take the simple case of 4 elements. Perhaps you could do a diagram to show how the space is to be distributed (a sketch will do).Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of

```
.flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
}
```

You don't need   `<div class="center"></div>`

Comment: Are you sure this will center say the 2nd element when there are 3 elements? space-between puts the same space between each pair of elements, so unless they are all of the same size the 2nd one will not be centered.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure. But If one of either the first or third element is already taking say 50% width of the parent container, do you think the 2nd element can be centered relative to the parent container? Only if it's going to overlap I think

Comment: @yuxufabio `<div class="center"></div>` is just for presentational purposes. It's a dot to show where the center of container div is. I forgot to mention that

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any way to do this using only a flexbox with the different-sized elements as direct children, if you need support for an arbitrary number of elements.  My recommendation would be to use a flexbox with an extra layer of child elements.  Or you could use a table, but I think the flexbox is cleaner.

```css
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  
}

.center{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 0px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  
}

.item{
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.narrowContent{
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.content{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}


.mytable{
  display: table;
  height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

.myrow{
  display: table-row;
}

.mycell{
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
Flex:
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="center">

  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="narrowContent">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="content">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="content">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="narrowContent">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="content">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>


Table:
<div class="mytable">
  <div class="center">

  </div>
  <div class="myrow">
    <div class="mycell">
      <div class="narrowContent">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mycell">
      <div class="narrowContent">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mycell">
      <div class="content">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mycell">
      <div class="content">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mycell">
      <div class="narrowContent">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mycell">
      <div class="content">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could come this kind of approch. We can get number of child element and find the middle element and create your center DIV inside there

```
<div>
   <div></div>
   <div> <div class="center"> </div></div> <----Added new center div element inside here
   <div></div>
</div>
```

or

if dont have an one middle element we can add the center DIV between two middle element

```
<div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div> <--------------Added new center div element here
   <div></div>
</div>
```

```js
function findMiddle(){

  //get all the child elements
  var childsEl = document.getElementById('parent').children;
  
  //get the parant element referance
  var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
  
  //find the middle index from parent child element
  var middle = (childsEl.length - 1) / 2;

  //Create the center div element
  var centerElement = document.createElement("div");

  //use regex to check the sigle middle div element is avaibale or not
  let regexPattern = /^-?[0-9]+$/;
  let res = regexPattern.test(middle);
  
  //Depending on the middle element availability
  if(res){

    //Add new class to center element (deside W/H background color)
    centerElement.classList.add("centerItem")
    
    //add class to parent element of the center element  
    //and make it as flex and make it vertically any horizontally center
    //in the parent div
    childsEl[middle].classList.add('centerChild')
    
    //apend the new center element inside the middle element (now it 
    //parent of center element)
    childsEl[middle].appendChild(centerElement);
  }else{
  
    //here posistion has set as relative
    centerElement.classList.add("centerItem")

    //move the ceneter element down to show as center of the container
    //If you use same div height instead of make this element center 
    //from it parent. you can get the height of the one child element
    //make half as top: ???
    centerElement.style.top = parent.scrollHeight / 2 + "px";

    //create a new alement between two divs if we dont have middle div 
    //element
    parent.insertBefore(centerElement, childsEl[Math.round(middle)]);
  
  
  }
  
}
findMiddle()
```

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.first {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}

.second {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}

.third {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.centerItem {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  
  /* position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) */
}

.centerChild{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex" id="parent">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second"></div>
  <div class="third"></div>
</div>
```

[Add any number of DIV element and see](https://jsfiddle.net/Janaka_Ravindra/bheus7dx/)